# Postgresql running inside docker container (gcp remote instance) can't be accessed from dbeaver locally

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, containers, dbeaver

I'm running postgres as an indipendent service in an independent docker container on a remote instance (gcp) - see docker compose file below.

Postgres is actually working - if I access it through the container, I can connect and do operations within it (create db, users ...).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFsms.png)

But, when I try to connect to the postgres db via dbeaver I always get a **Connection attempt timed out** error.

Here my dbeaver configuration:
Host: 172.17.0.1
Port: 5432
DB - Username - Password: postgres (as defined in the docker compose file)

Firewall rule has been set up in gcp. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaZer.png)

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:latest
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
            - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        ports:
             - "5432:5432"
        logging:
             options:
                  max-size: 10m
                  max-file: "3"
        volumes:
             - /opt/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:latest
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - /opt/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
            - /opt/airflow_logs:/opt/airflow/logs
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3

    scheduler:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:latest
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - webserver
        environment:
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        volumes:
            - /opt/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
            - /opt/airflow_logs:/opt/airflow/logs
        command: scheduler
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access your docker container executing the following:

```
docker exec -it postgres bash
```

Here you are inside your postgres container, you can try to access it using:

```
psql -U postgres -p
```

And then instert postgres as password. If that fails, that user probably doesn't have permissions to log in. You can try to log using root user with password root, that should work and also should let you connect from dbbeaver. From inside the container you could upgrade your user's permissions using the root user.

Comment: The problem is not accessing the postgres within the container (that always worked properly), but accessing postgres from an external client such as DBeaver.

Comment: As i tried to explain, your problem is that your user doesn't have permissions to access externally, so you probably need to use the root one. The process described is just so that you can check that out.

Comment: I did all the steps you suggested, and I can confirm I can login via CLI in the container with all the users (login), and that all the postgres user has all the right permission to access externally. But, still, can't access from DBeaver :(

Comment: Do you have any postgresql instances in your local pc? If so try to change the port of your postgre container setting it to ports: "5433:5432" Then you can try to access it using port 5433

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect using dbeaver you need to used `localhost` as host instead of `172.17.0.1` because this the db server inside docker compose network.